# Is there a way to send SQL data to App Insights in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-application-insights

I have a web service application which connects to an Azure SQL instance. I recently configured it for App Analytics. When I open the 'Application Map' blade, I see this -

[image]

I would like to use App Insight Analytics like this -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-import, but the blog I found it on stated that it was for noSQL data.

Is there a way that I can use app insights to periodically pull from the SQL database connected to my application and render that information graphically? Or do I need to use csv file/noSQL schema?

Thanks!

Comment: To get thing clear. Are you interested in seeing the commands etc. of the Azure Sql instance your web app connects to or do you want to upload data to query using Application Insights Analytics? These are quite different things.

Comment: I believe that I want to upload the Data from my SQL instance to application insights. My understanding is that once valid data is available and populated in the Analytics schema, I would need to query it like this:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-using  in order to display the graphical/visuals. If this is not feasible then I'll explore using Azure Blob storage with my application, since that is what the guide suggests

Answer (score 1):

According to the article: [*"Import data into Analytics"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-import), it just enables us to import JSON or DSV (delimiter-separated values - comma, semicolon or tab) files and the data should be uploaded to Azure storage, it does not support importing data from SQL database directly.

If you’d like to send SQL data to Application Insights Analytics, you can query data from your SQL database first and upload the data/result to Azure storage, and then make REST call to notify Application Insights to ingest the data.